# Maintain image resolution regardless of screen size

Tags: html, css, ionic4

I am developing a mobile app on ionic 4 which has an image on the main screen. I wish to keep the resolution of the image regardless of screen size. i.e if the screen is 300px wide, my image remains 666px wide and you just have to scroll left and right to view the entire thing.

I tried marking the pixel width and height as "!important" in the css file just the image just squashes

http code

```
      <head>
        <style>
        .map
        {
          position: relative;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          height: 887px !important;
          width: 666px !important;
        }

   </style>
 </head>


 <ion-content padding>
   <pinch-zoom>
     <div>
       <img class = "map"
       id = "map"
       src = "../../assets/img/limerickmap.JPG"
       alt = "map"/> 
       <img class = "avatar"
       id = "avatar"
       src = "../../assets/img/satan.png"
       alt = "avatar" />
     </div>
   </pinch-zoom>  

 </ion-content>
```

Comment: have you tried `display: inline-block;` ?

Comment: Or simply block for your div

Comment: no luck, same outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to keep the image resolution regardless of viewport size.

Rudi Urbanek's answer simply doubles the viewport size of the image, so if your image is 666px and your viewport width is 300px; the image will be displayed at `600px`.

This does not solve the question you asked.

## So....

Instead, you should set the width to be "automatic" and the browser will take the width of the specified/child element (image).

It also helps to know two things:

- HTML `img` tags without width or height will always default to the natural size of the image.
- CSS percentage widths or heights will be the percentage of the screen size *or* of the parent in some situations.

Try this:

```
    .map
    {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        overflow: visible; /* should not be needed but will ensure your image is not cut off */
    }
```

And your `<img>` tag already does not specify `width=""` or `height=""`, so that's good for this scenario.

([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width))

Answer (score 1):

just use min-width if your image is greater than your prefered size you can add max-width too don't use height so it scales proportionally

```css
img {
  min-width: 200%;
  max-width: 200%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/thumb700x/heic0910s.jpg">
```

Comment: Hah, well there's 15Mb of my internet quota I'm not getting back..... `:-)`

Comment: had to match the div with the same dimension. Thanks!